# Das Internet wird zum(als?) Kommunizieren mit Leuten aus aller Welt verwendet

Tags: grammar, meaning, preposition

When do you use **zu** and **als** ?

> Die Relativpronomen werden **zur** Bezeichnung entweder feminin, maskulin verwendet, oder neutrum.

Can I use **als** instead of **zu**  in this context ?

Here's another example :

> Dieses Auto hier ist zum Fahren

oder

> Dieses Auto hier ist für das Fahren.

In this context one cannot use **als**

Are there rules when to use **als** and **zu** ?

Comment: Als Kommunikationsmittel zum Kommunizieren

Comment: Nicht ' als Kommunizierung' ?

Comment: Nein, weil es das Wort "Kommunizierung" nicht gibt. Das heist "Kommunikation". "Kommunizieren" ist das zugehörige Verb.

Answer (score 3):

*Kommunizierung* is in any case incorrect, *Kommunikation* being the form you would be looking for. *Kommunizieren* is regarded as a 'little less incorrect', but it is not good German.

> Das Internet wird für die Kommunikation  verwendet.

*Als* specifically denotes a relationship in which something is used as something else. For instance,

> Manchmal benutze ich ein Buch als Hammer.

...meaning that sometimes, I use a book as a hammer. In other words, the hammer is not the ultimate function but the kind of tool into which I have turned the book.

Answer (score 0):

*Als* (in that use) means *in function/role of*. Hence it is feasable for nouns.

> Als Lehrer/Hammer/Bezeichung/Blumenvase...

*Zu* (in that use) *for the doing*. It works for actions that are phrased as the generic noun that is like *das Verben*.

> Zum Arbeiten/Schlafen/Kommunizieren...

*Kommunikation* is a thing. *Das Kommunizieren* is an activity that is just made a noun grammatically.